# Как подключить dubug на шаблоне advanсed?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь подключить debug  панель на шаблоне advanced просмотр интренета ни чего не дал кроме как вот этого

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug']['class'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
    $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii']['class'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
    $config['modules']['gii']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
}
```

для basic и вот этого

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];
    $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
    $config['modules']['gii']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];

}
```

но куда подключать я так и не понял если в config/main/php  выпадает просто белый экран. Не подскажете как подключить debug и gii  если сайт выложен на сервере.

Comment: Оно вроде по умолчанию уже есть.... у basic: `config/web.php` внизу  перед `return $config;`......., у advanced в `backend/config/main-local.php` и `frontend/config/main-local.php` перед `return $config;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо оформляйте ответ  именно frontend/config/main-local.php не проверял :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно такие вещи уже по умолчанию есть в шаблонах basic и advanced, предоставляемые фреймворком.

Если конкретно, то у `basic` шаблона настройка:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {

...

}
```

находится (а если нет - то туда надо вставить) по пути:

`config/web.php` в самом низу перед `return $config;`

У `advanced` шаблона настройка:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {

...

}
```

находится (а если нет - то туда надо вставить) по двум путям:

`backend/config/main-local.php` и `frontend/config/main-local.php` перед `return $config;`

Comment: находится спасибо