# Подключение dubug на шаблоне advanсed

Tags: yii2

мне надо подключить dubug на шаблоне advanсed, я видел [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526452/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dubug-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-advan%D1%81ed) и прочие.
ответ заключается в том, что в файлах backend/config/main-local.php и frontend/config/main-local.php перед return $config; вставить код

> ```
> if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
> // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
> $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
> $config['modules']['debug']['class'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
> $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
>
> $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
> $config['modules']['gii']['class'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
> $config['modules']['gii']['allowedIPs'] = ['*']; }
> ```

но я не понимаю как такое может быть, если изначально внешний вид файла frontend/config/main-local.php совершенно другой. У меня это так:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=etest_com',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        ],
    ],
];
```

вот ссылка на [гит](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/environments/prod/common/config/main-local.php)

Куда вставлять то этот код, чтоб работал дебагер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в `common/config/main-local.php` в секцию `modules` модуль дебагера, а также укажи, что его надо инициализировать в самом начале работы приложения.
У меня например вот так сделано. Айпишники свои или звездочку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]